# Which nuget package for OpenIdConnect authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, owin, openid-connect

I am trying to create a login mvc application in .NET through which any identity provider that supports OpenIdConnect for authentication and Oauth2.0 for authorization should be able to communicate. The objective is all my microservices will then call the login service ( which will act as a proxy) to perform single login and single logout and authorization via different identity providers such as Ping Identity or Okta or perhaps Azure AD.
Which Nuget package will be best to use in my login mvc application? **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect** or **Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect**. If there is any other library please shed some light. I am new in OpenIdConnect and IDP providers so please help me out here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect** for ASP.NET Core projects and **Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect** if you are using .NET Framework.

Comment: ok @Tore thanks for your reply but just for info who has edge Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect or Owin not considering .NET framework or .NET Core

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect is the more modern one if you are on .NET Core/.NET.  For example https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/5.0.6  only works on .NET 5.0 for example.